# How do I find the next commit in Git? (child/children of ref)

Tags: git, version-control

`ref^` refers to the commit before `ref`. What about getting the commit *after* `ref`?

For example, if I `git checkout 12345`, how do I check out the next commit?

Yes, Git's a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) node pointer struct tree whatever.  **How do I find the commit after this one?**

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761825/referencing-the-child-of-a-commit-in-git

Comment: See also "[`git children-of`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2264471/6309)"!

Answer (score 239, accepted):

To list all the commits, starting from the current one, and then its child, and so on - basically standard git log, but going the other way in time, use something like

```
git log --reverse --ancestry-path 894e8b4e93d8f3^..master
```

where 894e8b4e93d8f3 is the first commit you want to show.

N.b. When using a DOS command prompt, you must *escape the caret*:

```
git log --reverse --ancestry-path 894e8b4e93d8f3^^..master
```

Comment: For the specific case in the original question, just substitute `HEAD^` for `894e8b4e93d8f3^`.

Comment: Maybe, add --oneline  is a better brief output result.

Comment: I need to use `...`, `^..` fails silently

Comment: Getting `fatal: unrecognized argument: --ancestry-path` in git version 1.7.1

Comment: This will only work if `master` is on the ancestry path of the current commit. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39566420/5353461)'s second code snippet  for a solution which will work in all cases.

Comment: I don't see the point of adding `--reverse` here. It's just a preference, and an unneeded option as part of an answer that could be simpler.

Comment: So if you want to get the actual next commit in one line I used `git rev-list HEAD~$(expr $(git rev-list --ancestry-path <commit>.. --count) - 1) --max-count=1`

Answer (score 42):

The creator of [Hudson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%28software%29) (now [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29)), [Kohsuke Kawaguchi](https://github.com/kohsuke) published (November 2013):
[kohsuke / git-children-of](https://gist.github.com/kohsuke/7590246):

> Given a commit, find immediate children of that commit.

```sh
#!/bin/bash -e
# given a commit, find immediate children of that commit.
for arg in "$@"; do
  for commit in $(git rev-parse $arg^0); do
    for child in $(git log --format='%H %P' --all | grep -F " $commit" | cut -f1 -d' '); do
      git describe $child
    done
  done
done
```

---

As illustrated by [this thread](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2009/01/msg143820.html), in a VCS based on history represented by a [DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), there is not "one parent" or "one child".

```
        C1 -> C2 -> C3
      /               \
A -> B                  E -> F
      \               /
        D1 -> D2 ----/
```

The ordering of commits is done by "topo-order" or "date-order" (see the [GitPro book](http://book.git-scm.com/3_reviewing_history_-_git_log.html)).

But since [Git 1.6.0](http://kerneltrap.org/node/16515), you can list the children of a commit.

```
git rev-list --children
git log --children
```

---

Note: for [parent commits](http://progit.org/book/ch6-1.html), you have the same issue, with the suffix `^` to a revision parameter meaning the *first* parent of that commit object. `^<n>` means the `<n>`th parent (i.e. `rev^`  is equivalent to `rev^1`).

If you are on branch `foo` and issue "`git merge bar`" then `foo` will be the first parent. 
I.e.: The first parent is the branch you were on when you merged, and the second is the commit on the branch that you merged in.

Comment: `git rev-list --children` sure looks like what I want, but it doesn't DWIM.  It appears to list all the parents and their children.  I suppose I can list them all and parse through them... bleh, but its something.

Comment: @Schwern: true, `git rev-list --children` is not for listing just children, but for listing parents *with their children*... you always need to parse.

Comment: I tried that code on a commit with two children: `$ git children0of 9dd5932`
`fatal: No annotated tags can describe '71d7b5dd89d241072a0a078ff2c7dfec05d52e1f'.`
`However, there were unannotated tags: try --tags.`
 What output do you get?

Comment: @TomHale I cannot test it right now, but ask a new question (with OS and Git version), that way everyone can test.

Comment: The only problem with `git-children-of` is that it uses [git describe](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) that attempts to format the SHA as human-readable, which can fail with @TomHale's error, and gives results like `v1.0.4-14-g2414721` that are confusing if you expected a SHA. Replacing it with a simple `echo` makes this an excellent tool, thanks!

Comment: @TomHale 's problem can also be fixed with `git describe --all --always $child` so it will fall back to the abbreviated hash if it can't find a ref to use. If you have no tags whatsoever or only started using them recently, `--all --contains` might give more useful names, but since they are relative to branch heads they won't stay valid as new commits occur.

Comment: @LeBleu Thank you for the feedback. How would you modify the script from the answer to accommodate that particular scenario?

Answer (score 24):

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path commit1..commit2
```

I set `commit1` as the current commit and `commit2` to the current head, and this returns a list of all commits which build a path between `commit1` and `commit2`.

The last line of the output is the child of `commit1` (on the path to `commit2`).

Comment: So just add `| tail -1` to get the child.

Comment: Or add `| Select -Last 1` for powershell

Answer (score 13):

I know what you mean. It's frustrating to have plentiful syntax for going to previous commits, but none to go to the next ones. In a complex history, the problem of "what is the next commit" becomes rather hard, but then in complex merging the same hardness emerges with 'previous' commits as well. In the simple case, inside a single branch with a linear history (even just locally for some limited number of commits) it would be nice and make sense to go forward and backward.

The real problem with this, however, is that the children commits are not referenced; it's a backwards-linked list only. Finding the child commit takes a search, which isn't too bad, but it is probably not something Git wants to put into the refspec logic.

At any rate, I came upon this question, because I simply want to step forward in the history one commit at a time, doing tests, and sometimes you have to step forward and not backward. Well, with some more thought I came up with this solution:

Pick a commit ahead of where you're at. This could probably be a branch head. If you're at branch~10, "git checkout branch~9", "git checkout branch~8" to get the next after that, "git checkout branch~7" and so on.

Decrementing the number should be really easy in a script if you need it. A lot easier than parsing the Git rev-list.

Comment: While useful, it doesn't find the next commit. It walks towards the current commit.

Comment: Well then I suppose you could do:

"`BRANCH=master; git co $BRANCH~$[ $(git rev-list HEAD..$BRANCH | wc -l) - 1 ]`"

You've got to go towards a branch, no way around that.

Answer (score 13):

All of Git's internal arrows are one-way, pointing backwards.  There is therefore no short convenient syntax for moving forwards: it's just not possible.

It *is* possible to "move against the arrows", but the way to do it is surprising if you haven't seen it before, and then obvious afterward.  Let's say we have:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E   <-- last
        ^
        |
         \--------- middle
```

Using `middle~2` follows the arrows twice from `C` back to `A`.  So how do we move from `C` to `D`?  The answer is: we start at `E`, using the name `last`, and work backwards until we get to `middle`, *recording the points we visit along the way*.  Then we just move as far as we want in the direction of `last`: move one step to `D`, or two to `E`.

This is particularly important when we have branches:

```
          D--E   <-- feature1
         /
...--B--C   <-- master
         \
          F--G   <-- feature2
```

Which commit is one step after `C`?  There's no correct answer until you add to the question: *in the direction of feature___* (fill in the blank).

To enumerate the commits between `C` (excluding `C`) itself and, say, `G`, we use:

```
git rev-list --topo-order --ancestry-path master..feature2
```

The `--topo-order` makes sure that even in the presence of complex branching-and-merging, the commits come out in topologically-sorted order.  This is only required if the chain isn't linear.  The `--ancestry-path` constraint means that when we work backwards from `feature2`, we only list commits that have commit `C` as one of their own ancestors.  That is, if the graph—or the relevant chunk of it anyway—actually looks like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
 \     \
  \     F--G--J   <-- feature2
   \         /
    H-------I   <-- feature3
```

Then a simple request of the form `feature2..master` enumerates commits `J`, `G` and `I`, and `F` and `H` in some order.  With `--ancestry-path` we knock out `H` and `I`: they are not descendants of `C`, only of `A`.  With `--topo-order` we make sure that the actual enumeration order is `J`, then `G`, then `F`.

The `git rev-list` command spills these hash IDs out on its standard output, one per line.  To move one step forward in the direction of `feature2`, then, we just want the *last* line.

It's possible (and tempting and can be useful) to add `--reverse` so that `git rev-list` prints the commits in reversed order after generating them.  This does work, but if you use it in a pipeline like this:

```
git rev-list --topo-order --ancestry-path --reverse <id1>...<id2> | head -1
```

to just get the "next commit in the direction of id2", and there is a very long list of commits, the `git rev-list` command can get a broken pipe when it tries to write to `head` which has stopped reading its input and exited.  Since broken-pipe errors are normally ignored by the shell, this mostly works.  Just make sure they're ignored in *your* usage.

It's also tempting to add `-n 1` to the `git rev-list` command, along with `--reverse`.  Don't do it!  That makes `git rev-list` stop after walking one step *back*, and then reverse the (one-entry) list of commits visited.  So this just produces `<id2>` every time.

#### Important side note

Note that with "diamond" or "benzene ring" graph fragments:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M--...  <-- last
      \    /
       K--L
```

moving one commit "forward" from `H` towards `last` will get you *either* `I` *or* `K`.  There is nothing you can do about that: both commits are one step forward!  If you then start from the resulting commit and go another step, you're now committed to whichever path you started on.

The cure for this is to avoid moving one step at a time and getting locked into path-dependent chains.  Instead, if you plan to visit an entire ancestry-path chain, *before doing anything else*, make a *complete list of all commits in the chain:*

```
git rev-list --topo-order --reverse --ancestry-path A..B > /tmp/list-of-commits
```

Then, visit each commit in this list, one at a time, and you'll get the entire chain.  The `--topo-order` will make sure you hit `I`-and-`J` in that order, and `K`-and-`L` in that order (though there's no easy way to predict whether you'll do the I-J pair before or after the K-L pair).

Comment: "*There's no correct answer until you add to the question: in the direction of feature___*" This is a very good point. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 12):

In the case where you don't have a particular "destination" commit in mind, but instead want to see child commits that might be on ***any*** branch, you can use this command:

```bash
git rev-list --children --all | grep ^${COMMIT}
```

If you want to see all children ***and grand-children***, you have to use `rev-list --children` recursively, like so:

```bash
git rev-list --children --all | \
egrep ^\($(git rev-list --children --all | \
           grep ^${COMMIT} | \
           sed 's/ /|/g')\)
```

(The version that gives *only* grand-children would use a more complex `sed` and/or `cut`.)

Finally, you can feed that into a `log --graph` command to see the tree structure, like so:

```bash
git log --graph --oneline --decorate \
\^${COMMIT}^@ \
$(git rev-list --children --all | \
  egrep ^\($(git rev-list --children --all | \
             grep ^${COMMIT} | \
             sed 's/ /|/g')\))
```

*Note*: the above commands all assume that you've set the shell variable `${COMMIT}` to some reference (branch, tag, sha1) of the commit whose children you're interested in.

Comment: this answers the question I did not know how to formulate for google and stackoverflow, but was trying to ask. thank you for proactively recognizing the need

Comment: for me `${COMMIT}` doesnt esist, but you could use `$(git rev-parse HEAD)
` instead

Comment: sorry, added a note about `${COMMIT}`.

Answer (score 10):

### Two practical answers:

#### One Child

Based on [@Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21032988/5353461), I hacked up the `child` alias in my `.gitconfig`.

It works as expected in the default case, and is also versatile.

```
# Get the child commit of the current commit.
# Use $1 instead of 'HEAD' if given. Use $2 instead of curent branch if given.
child = "!bash -c 'git log --format=%H --reverse --ancestry-path ${1:-HEAD}..${2:\"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\"} | head -1' -"
```

It defaults to giving the child of HEAD (unless another commit-ish argument is given) by following the ancestry one step toward the tip of the current branch (unless another commit-ish is given as second argument).

Use `%h` instead of `%H` if you want the short hash form.

#### Multiple children

With a detached HEAD (there is no branch) or to get all children regardless of branches:

```
# For the current (or specified) commit-ish, get the all children, print the first child 
children = "!bash -c 'c=${1:-HEAD}; set -- $(git rev-list --all --not \"$c\"^@ --children | grep $(git rev-parse \"$c\") ); shift; echo $1' -"
```

Change the `$1` to `$*` to print all the children.

You can also change `--all` to a commit-ish to display only the children which are ancestors of that commit—in other words, to display only the children “in the direction of” the given commit. This may help you narrow the output down from many children to just one.

Answer (score 6):

I've tried many different solutions and none worked for me. I had to come up with my own.

**Find the next commit**

```
function n() {
    git log --reverse --pretty=%H master | grep -A 1 $(git rev-parse HEAD) | tail -n1 | xargs git checkout
}
```

**Find the previous commit**

```
function p() {
    git checkout HEAD^1
}
```

Comment: What programming language? [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)? [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell)? [C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell)? [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)?

Answer (score 4):

I have this alias in `~/.gitconfig`

```
first-child = "!f() { git log  --reverse --ancestry-path --pretty=%H $1..${2:-HEAD} | head -1; }; f"
```

Comment: [Useful for Maven developers](https://gist.github.com/jglick/66974651f7c0c3ffed5945b3f2d2ebd4).

Comment: what is `f()`? And it needs to be `head -1` to be the first child, otherwise this will simply report the HEAD.

Comment: @Xerus Because it uses some "complex" shell syntax, and git will not recognize it if not wrapped in `f()`. Yes, `head -1` is a brave guess.

Comment: Nice! Tweaked mine to: ```nextref = "!f() { git log  --reverse --ancestry-path --pretty=%H $1..HEAD | head -${2:-1} | tail -1; }; f"``` so you can choose how far ahead, optionally

Answer (score 3):

On the terminal:

```
$ git log --format='%H %P' --all --reflog | grep -F " [commit-hash]" | cut -f1 -d' '
```

Or in .gitconfig, section [alias]:

```
children = "!f() { git log --format='%H %P' --all --reflog | grep -F \" $1\" | cut -f1 -d' '; }; f"
```

Answer (score 2):

If the child commits are all on some branch, you can use `gitk --all commit^..`, where "commit" is something identifying the commit.  For example, if the commit's abbreviated SHA-1 hash value is c6661c5, then type `gitk --all c6661c5^..`

You will probably need to enter the full SHA-1 hash value into gitk's "SHA1 ID:" cell.  You will need the full SHA-1 hash value, which for this example can be obtained via `git rev-parse c6661c5`.

Alternatively, `git rev-list --all --children | grep '^c6661c5883bb53d400ce160a5897610ecedbdc9d'` will produce a line containing all the children of this commit, presumably whether or not there is a branch involved.

Answer (score 1):

This shows a list of all children of current HEAD in separate lines:

```
git rev-list --parents --all | awk -v h="$(git rev-parse HEAD)" 'index($0,h)>1{print$1}'
```

It just prints all commits that have HEAD as their parent.

You can speed it up a little bit, by putting `^HEAD` before `|`, then the ancestors of HEAD will not be searched.

If you want to print children of another commit or branch, just put it in the place of `HEAD` (in the faster version in both `HEAD` places).

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was using it on a childless HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the next child the following way:

```
git log --reverse --children -n1 HEAD (where 'n' is the number of children to show)
```

Comment: for me this shows not the first child, it shows the current commit

Comment: This does not show children of the commit. It shows current commit. If you provide -n2 instead, it will show previous commit and the current one, but no next ones to the current commit. Which renders it useless because you can just look history.

Answer (score 0):

[Tomas Lycken's response in *Using Git commits to drive a live coding session*](http://www.jayway.com/2015/03/30/using-git-commits-to-drive-a-live-coding-session/#comment-282667) shows a neat way of doing it if you can create a well-defined tag at the end of your commit stack. Essentially

```
git config --global alias.next '!git checkout `git rev-list HEAD..demo-end | tail -1`'
```

where "demo-end" is the last tag.

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers assume that you have a branch containing the commit you're looking for.

In my case, the commit I was looking for wasn't on [`git rev-list --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) since no branch contained that.

I ended up looking through `gitk --reflog` manually.

If you can't find your commit even in the reflog, try either:

- [`git fsck --full`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery) to list dangling (i.e. not in any branch) commits, or
- [`git fsck --lost-found`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck#git-fsck---lost-found) to make refs pointing to dangling commits to apply techniques in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a command to rapidly checkout next commit.
I ended up with this alias:

```
[alias]
next = "!f() { CMIT=$(git log --ancestry-path --format=%H ${commit}..${1} | tail -1) && git checkout $CMIT; }; f"
```

You need to specify the branch you want to traverse, eg.:

```
git next master
```

You can add it to your `.gitconfig` file by directly editing it.

An example of its output:

```
~/home/myRepo | dd9e66ee  git next master
Previous HEAD position was dd9e66e Update README
HEAD is now at d71c74b Rename project; update to JUnit5
```

By running this command you go in [detached head mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-my-git-repo-enter-a-detached-head-state), of course :)

Answer (score 0):

I get the next child ref using following way:

```
git rev-list --children --reverse b3443a2^.. | sed -n 1p | awk '{print $2}'
```

1. Get the ref list with children of specific commit to the HEAD in reverse order
2. Use the first line
3. Print the next child ref

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search *all* commits in your Git object database, not just those referenced by some ref, then it doesn't seem like there is a practical way to do it with just the standard tools. Though it's possible iterate through and inspect every commit object in the database with just Git plumbing commands and `bash`, that will be too slow to be practical for most repositories.

I wrote a program which performs this task quickly:

https://github.com/CyberShadow/misc/blob/master/git-find-child-commit.d

(To run it, install `dub`, then execute the source file like a script; the package manager will do the rest.)

Answer (score -1):

Each commit stores a pointer to its parent (parents, in case of a merge (standard) commit).

So, there isn't any way to point to a child commit (if there is one) from the parent.

Comment: Commit cannot store pointers to its children, as additional child commits (branching points) can be added at later point.

Comment: @Jakub I don't really follow.  They can't be added later?

Comment: Jakub: Thats exactly what I said. 'Each commit stores pointers only to its parent.'

Comment: @Schwern: Commits in git are immutable (which has nice consequence of accountability), so pointers to children cound't "be added later".  One of the reasons is that identifier of commit (used e.g. in "parent" links) depends on the contents of the comit; this is the only solution in distributed system, without central numbering authority.  Also "children" of commits depends on the branches you have, and this in turn can be different from repository to repository (and commits are the same in each repository).

Comment: @becomingGuru: My comment was about why it is impossible to have pointers to child comits in the commit object.

Comment: @becomingGuru I down voted it.  It may be true, but it does not answer my question.  The question is "how do I find the next commit in git?"  It is not "does a git commit store a pointer to its children?"