# Referring to the previous/next commit in git?

Tags: git, commit

I have seen git commands use a syntax such as `HEAD~`, but I haven't been able to find this syntax in the Git [Reference Manual](http://git-scm.com/docs).

Here is what I have understood: `<commit>~<n>` refers to the commit *<n>* steps earlier than *<commit>* (where *<n>* is an integer number), and `commit~` simply means the same and that *<n>* implicitly is one.

Now, is this correct? In that case, does this always work? What if *<commit>* is the result of a merge between two branches, which commit will then `<commit>~` refer to? Is there some corresponding syntax for referring to the next commit or the commit *<n>* steps later?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have a very clear explanation of how this works in the chapter on [Acenstry References in Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References):

- `~` is used to get the first parent.
- `^` can be used to get the other parents (`^2`, for example, for a merge).

But you don't have a simple way to reference the next commit, even if [there are more convoluted ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git) to get it.

Comment: Thanks. The reference manual was apparently not the right place to look — I thought it would cover Git's syntax as well.

Answer (score 19):

To simply answer the question from title (since that's what got me here from Google):

To checkout the previous commit:

```
git checkout HEAD^
```

To checkout the next commit (assuming there's no branching):

```
git checkout `git log --reverse --ancestry-path HEAD..master | head -n 1 | cut -d \  -f 2`
```

Answer (score 14):

Inspired by @cexbrayat's answer, I find it useful to think of it this way:

How to refer to something in a commit's ancestry, where a commit can have multiple parents:

- `^n` specifies which parent
- `~n` specifies which generation

Both default to one.

Comment: That's a quite good rule :) Although it breaks down when neither `^n` nor `~n` is specified.

Comment: That just leaves the commit hash itself, which refers to.. itself.  I suppose I should have specified that a commit hash should be included as well.

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I guess you mean that they default to one, like arguments to a function in programming can have default values if you don't specify them? I'm thinking that if you have a function that takes both which generation and which parent and returns a commit reference, and if you don't specify any of them, you will just have the commit you start out with. So in this case the generation would be 0 even though you don't specify which generation. Although I realize that which parent is really only relevant when the generation in 1, so the two having such a function doesn't make so much sense.

Comment: In other words, the default value of the generation would be 0 if you don't specify which parent.

Comment: Well, what I mean by 'default to one':

Consider the expression '<SHA1>^'.

There is no specific value given for which parent you mean, so the first parent is returned.

Same with '<SHA1>~'.  No number is specified, so the first generation back is what it acts upon.

Answer (score 5):

To refer to most recent commit on the branch you can also use `@~1`

```
git checkout @~1
```

Comment: not sure if this the case everywhere, but in PowerShell on Windows that is `git checkout "@~1"`

Comment: No, it's not. It's the unique Shell Power of PowerShell ;-)

Comment: Now I will do `git rebase -i @~2` ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Like the OP, I was looking for the official documentation on this subject and found this SO question instead. See [Git - Revision Selection](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection).