# Move forward in git

Tags: git, git-checkout

Imagine I have this history 7-6-5-4-3-2-1-(first-commit)
Now I do the following command to go the commit 3 :

```
git checkout HEAD~3
```

What I should to go the commit 4? I tried `git checkout HEAD~-1` but it's not the right syntax. We assume that there's no other branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the next commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23796565/4323

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 7 is the oldest commit, then you'll do

```
git checkout HEAD^
```

otherwise, you'll use

```
git checkout HEAD@{1}
```