# Advancing x commits in git

Tags: git

I want to run a script that will run tests on a commit, advance X commits forward, and do the tests again, repeating until it can't go further

How do I take a certain commit I am checked-out on and advance it X commits? X could be 10 or 100.

One way I am thinking of, is to dump all commit hashes to a list, and jump on that list, but I wonder if there is a gittier way to do it

Comment: Sounds similar to `git-bisect`

Comment: yea but I want to do it manually not for bug searching, just for static analysis of the code. I don't have a bad or good condition.

Comment: If you start at the tip of the branch, you can go backwards. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062358/referring-to-the-previous-next-commit-in-git You could remember the commits you encounter in a list, then work through that in reverse. Note that commits can have both multiple ancestors and successors, so next and prev are not well defined.

Comment: Still sounds like `git-bisect`; you seem to think that *good* and *bad* are exactly that and it's for debugging, rather they are pointers for *Reference A* and *Reference B*; merely to checkout each commit one-by-one between A and B where you mark good or bad, in your case this is irrelevant you can mark all as "good" let it iterate through for you to run your tests on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

```
base=master
cur=10
step=3
while (( $cur >= 0 ))
do 
    git show ${base}~${cur}
    ((cur -= $step))
done
```

Instead of `git show` you probably want to checkout and run something.

Answer (score 0):

Because of branches and merges there isn't necessarily a single "next" or "previous" commit even when you are "between" commits `A` and `B`:

```
                  o - o - o
                /           \
... - A - * - o               o - B
                \           /
                  o ------ o
```

If you are on node `*` there is an obvious next/previous commit, the next is the rightward node `o` and the previous is node `A`.  But after you move forward one, what's the *next* "next" commit?  Should we traverse upwards to the three-node line, or downwards to the two-node line?

`git bisect` does a lot of tricky stuff to minimize the number of nodes tested while also handling (or trying to handle) these branch-and-merge cases.

Mayvbe you are not looking to test some binary condition.  For instance, suppose your static analysis tool is simply generating a bunch of metrics and you want to find out, e.g., that "every N commits / minutes / hours / days, metric A tends to go up somewhat while metric B tends to go down, but during this particular period the trend reversed."  In this case you will need to define your own metric for "every N commits" or "every N hours" or whatnot, probably by running `git rev-list` and working with raw commit IDs from then on.

In general, `git rev-list` is the tool that handles this, and in fact, `git bisect` itself uses `git rev-list` with `--bisect` (see [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) for details; note that it stores names in the `refs/bisect` name space so that it can be used iteratively).  The rev-list command has several additional bisect variants that you may find useful.