# git, get child commits that are not on a branch

Tags: git, history

I have a commit A.
I need to find all commits that are based on A.

But all this commits not on any branch. I can't just see history of some branch.

How to solve this?

Comment: how do you know they exist at all? Are you trying to undo a reset? Try `git reflog`

Comment: I remember they been made long time ago.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git