# git log reverse and then limit the results to one

Tags: git

I am at the commit on `master`, and I need to get to the next commit wrt `origin/master`.

```
git log --ancestry-path --date-order --reverse HEAD..origin/master
```

or a similar `git rev-list` command gives me the right commits, properly reversed, so I could `|head -n 1` that and be done with it.

However, I wonder it it's possible to get it by using just one process (one git invokation). Limiting with `-1` limits first, and then reverses the list, which I not what I need.

How to accomplish this?

I know what a DAG is, I also know enough graph theory to understand why `-1` behaves like that. What I'm asking here is not a matter of theory, it's a matter of using a tool used in software development.

Comment: Without the `--reverse`, you could do `| tail -n 1`, but your specification of 'just one process' excludes that. That seems unnecessarily strict, but your question, your rules. Anyway, have you considered reporting the poor behavior in combining `-1` and `--reverse` as a bug?

Comment: @Novelocrat I have considered it, but that was before I read the mailing list archive.

Answer (score 9):

I'm 90% confident this can't be done in a single Git invocation for two reasons.

1. It just doesn't look like they've implemented it. Commits have pointers to their parents, not their children, which is why `--max-count` (`-1`) and `--skip` (which I also tried a bit) run before `--reverse`. Since Git's capable of printing in `--reverse` or not, it seems like running `-1` afterwards should be technically feasible, but perhaps there's an underlying reason it's not. Or perhaps they considered it and decided anyone could just `--reverse | head -n 1` like you're doing.
2. More importantly, you're not guaranteed a unique next commit, even when using `--ancestry-path`, so picking `--reverse -1` is ambiguous. Here's an example from the `--ancestry-path` description in the [git-log docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), where your `HEAD` could be commit `E`. If you're happy with `--date-order`, it's more of an academic issue, but the DAG nature of Git makes the whole "next commit" concept unsound.

> As an example use case, consider the following commit history:
>
> ```
>     D---E-------F
>    /     \       \
>   B---C---G---H---I---J
>  /                     \
> A-------K---------------L--M
> ```
>
> A regular D..M computes the set of commits that are ancestors of M, but excludes the ones that are ancestors of D. This is useful to see what happened to the history leading to M since D, in the sense that “what does M have that did not exist in D”. The result in this example would be all the commits, except A and B (and D itself, of course).
>
> When we want to find out what commits in M are contaminated with the bug introduced by D and need fixing, however, we might want to view only the subset of D..M that are actually descendants of D, i.e. excluding C and K. This is exactly what the --ancestry-path option does. Applied to the D..M range, it results in:
>
> ```
> E-------F
>  \       \
>   G---H---I---J
>                \
>                 L--M
> ```

Comment: Hi, thanks, however (see my update): "I know what a DAG is, I also know enough graph theory to understand why `-1` behaves like that. What I'm asking here is not a matter of theory, it's a matter of using a tool used in software development.". +1 however for the effort.

Comment: It still just appears unimplemented. I'l be pleased if someone discovers otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

This does what you want:

```
git rev-list --children HEAD...origin/master^ | tail -2 | head -1 | cut -d" " -f 2-
```

This will even print N children, if the history forks at this point.

You could wrap this into a git alias to make a single command.

For other solutions, see also [How do I find the next commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git)

Comment: Yes @Flavius, it is.  And one invocation of git.  And when turned into an alias, it would be one command.

Comment: @Flavius If this is not a solution, please explain why?

Comment: You could replace the tail/head/cut with a single call to `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: No, none of the presented answers is a solution ***in one git invokation***. Try to log a full commit entry (not an SHA). Yes, I know `... --reverse | grep -m2 -B99 "^commit ...  ` Great, but still this is not git itself figuring it out and not very elegant though. Whereas implementing hypothetical `git log --reverse -1` with the behavior like some here expected would do the job for any format.

Comment: @bloody while it may be complicated, git is only invoked once. Plenty of git commands are implemented as pipes through various UNIX utilities.

Comment: @EwanMellor, what's the rationale behind `...` vs `..` here? I found the answer helpful to my needs but it didn't log the commit I expected. Instead I used `| tail -1 | cut -d" " -f -1` and then `| xargs git log -1`. I'd probably also switch cut to `awk '{ print $1 }'`

Comment: You didn't get the point. Your answer may be a single invokation but it is NOT a reliable SOLUTION for the problem :D Read my comment with focus.

Answer (score 0):

I was also surprised that `-n 1` or `--max-count 1` applies before `--reverse` instead of after it.  This was discussed on the git list some time back: https://git.vger.kernel.narkive.com/e6fDRBef/patch-fix-git-rev-list-reverse-max-count-n
"I talked to Junio and he says the current behavior is here to stay."