# Find commits after a commit

Tags: git

I have a very deep git history

```
0000001
0000002
0000003
0000004
...
```

I used `git-bisect` to find the hash of an old issue which returned `0000003`. Turns out the solution may lie in one of the commits after this hash `0000002` or even more recent

I can use

```
git log 0000003
```

which will show the history of the project until that commit, but nothing after

```
0000003
0000004
...
```

I want to find the commits around / after `0000003` using only hashes - ie, I want to find `0000002` without manually scrolling all the history.

How is this done?

Comment: Did you read https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and look for the next few commits (the ones created after `00003`)

```
git log --reverse --pretty=format:%H --ancestry-path 3...master | head -3
```

With `3` being the SHA1 of the commit `00003`.

You have other techniques described in "[How do I find the next commit in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2263674/6309)".
For instance:

```
git rev-list HEAD..3 | tail -3
```

This assume those next commits are accessible from master or HEAD.

> In the case where you don't have a particular "destination" commit in mind, but instead want to see child commits that might be on any branch, you can use this command:

```
git rev-list --children --all | grep ^${COMMIT}
```

Comment: Cool :-) i learned something new `--ancestry-path` was not aware to that,

Answer (score 0):

`git bisect` is a good option as well as you used it already.

You can use the HEAD~X

```
# set X to be the number of commits you want to start with
git log HEAD~X

# Range: between HEAD to the previous X commits
git log HEAD...HEAD~X
```

Read [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) about commit range.