# Overwrote .git directory, recovering state from objects

Tags: git, .git-folder

I careless copied `.git` from one project (A) to another (B), with a remote `scp -r (A) (B)`.

I would like to recover a usable state of the git repo. I can remove (A)'s .git objects. From there, how can I best go about finding tips of git branches and rebuilding a useful state of the repo.

Unfortunately, I don't have another copy of (B), and my mistake wiped out the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Your only problem is restoring the refs.  All `B`'s objects are still there, but any of `A`'s names (branches, remotes, tags, ...) that matched `B` names overwrote the object pointers.

Start with

```
git fsck --root
```

which will show you dangling commits and all the roots, most projects have just one, you can then do `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --ancestry-path $the $dangling $commits --not $the $roots`.  Since the copy also overwrote your reflogs, if you stomped on *all* the refs this will find all your missing history.

Comment: Thanks, I've been using the grep suggestion to find children of the bad root https://stackoverflow.com/a/34030654/1020467

Answer (score 0):

For A you should be able to just clone a fresh copy of it (if there is a remote) into a new folder "A_copy":

- `git clone <url> A_copy`

or for a specific branch:

- `git clone <url> -b some_branch A_copy`

Then take the .git folder from this copy and drop it into your "broken" A. Then use `git status` to see what has changed.

If you want to revert either just use your new clone or you can do:

- `git reset HEAD --hard` - this takes you back to the state of HEAD.

---

For B, if you at least have the files and you want to turn it back into a repo you can just do the following:

- `git init` - makes the folder a git repo
- `git add -A` - note this will add everything in this folder so tidy up first if you need to and maybe add a .gitingore if required.
- `git commit -m "gehhh... had to start again :("`