# Ability to go to a child commit via relative refs

Tags: git

Let's say that I have a repo where A is the initial commit, where `HEAD` points to commit B, and where branch "foo-branch" points to commit C:

```
              A
              |
      HEAD -> B
              |
foo-branch -> C
              |
              D
```

I know I can get foo-branch to point to commit A (two parents up), via relative ref to HEAD, by running

`git branch -f foo-branch HEAD~1`

...but let's say that instead of going to a parent commit, I want to go to the child commit of foo-branch, commit D. **How do I do this using a relative ref to `HEAD`**?

As a note, in a purely fictional world, if the `#` token could be used to reference the opposite of `~`, I could run

`git branch -f foo-branch HEAD#2`

and it would point foo-branch to commit D. Purely fictional, but it gets my point across.

P.S. - I know that there could be issues if children of commit C branch anywhere down the chain, but for simplicity's sake, let's not incorporate branches into this question.

Comment: What if there is a commit E on a branch paralell to D branching out from C? which one would it choose? You could investigate possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git-child-children-of-ref)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58226704/1256452) which I started on before thinking about looking for duplicates.