# How to extract commit file from commit id in git?

Tags: git, command

I want to extract the commit file before the commit and the after the commit only using one commit id. Is there any way to extract this?

```
commit 471d4d60dc21fbccb8c6b4616a00238c245f78f6
Author: Gilles Sadowski <gilles@harfang.homelinux.org>
Date:   Mon Oct 28 01:51:42 2019 +0100

MATH-1500 (unit tests).
src/test/ ... linalg/FieldLUDecompositionTest.java

commit 9988a5b3c4779eadfad9ea0c4925f5b327317814
Author: Gilles Sadowski <gilles@harfang.homelinux.org>
Date:   Sun Oct 27 15:11:56 2019 +0100

Code upgraded following MATH-1500.
src/main/... nonstiff/AdamsNordsieckTransformer.java
```

In this case i want to extract file name "FieldLUDecompositionTest" before the commit and after the commit only using one commit id which is "471d4d60dc21fbccb8c6b4616a00238c245f78f6"

Comment: Note that you can also use `git show <commit-hash>:<path>` to extract a particular file from a particular commit without checking it out. Be aware that this sometimes skips line-ending conversions and smudge filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just move your head to the desired commit and copy the file to another location.
The procedure would be the following:

1. `git checkout 471d4d60dc21fbccb8c6b4616a00238c245f78f6` - you are now at the point where the file was not modified
2. Copy the file to another location.
3. `git checkout 9988a5b3c4779eadfad9ea0c4925f5b327317814` - this is the latest commit from your history
4. Copy the modified file to new location.

If you want more information about moving the head on a branch, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head-undo-commits).

Comment: Is there any easy way to automate your process?

Comment: what kind of automation we are talking about? if you have access to shell commands then yes.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to extract/restore a file from a commit is, with Git 2.23+ (August 2019) to use [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) ([less confusing than `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309))

```
git restore <SHA1>
```

To restore only one specific file from that old commit:

```
git restore <SHA1> -- path/to/file
```

That would update only your working tree by default.

---

Getting the *previous* SHA1 is easy:

```
471d4d60dc21fbccb8c6b4616a00238c245f78f6~
```

Git the *next* SHA1 is more complex: see "[How do I find the next commit in git? (child/children of ref)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39566420/6309)":

```
git log --format=%H --reverse --ancestry-path ${1:-HEAD}..${2:\"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\"} | head -1
```

More in [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58226704/6309))

```
git rev-list --topo-order --ancestry-path --reverse <id1>...<id2> | head -1
```

So you can make a script which will get the parent and child of a given commit, and use `git restore` to get/see the files of those commits.

Comment: This is does not get **a file** from a previous commit. It restores **all the files**.

Comment: @SandRock I agree. I have edited the answer to add the case where you want to restore **a file** from a previous commit.