# View Git history before a specific commit ID in the current branch

Tags: linux, git

I'd like some Git log command to list out the commits before some specific commit ID/hash in the current working branch.

E.g. Something like

```
git log --before <commit id>
```

But I haven't been able to find what the correct command to do this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give the commit hash as the ref to explore via log

```
git log <commitHash>
```

and it will output all history from that point, backwards, until initial commit.

Alternatively, if you need to exclude this specific commit itself, then refer to its parent with

```
git log <commitHash>^
```

---

**Sidenote** about your mention of "*in the current working branch*"

Branches are technically irrelevant here to tree traversal logic. This won't limit output to what's "in" the branch, largely because the common metaphor is quite bad : commits are just not "on" branches. Branches are to be seen as soft (and disposable) shortcuts to designate **one** commit in the tree.

Comment: Is there an easy composed command where you can say something like `git log [commitHash - 5 commits, commitHash + 5 commits]`?

Comment: No there's not, because ancestry goes only one way. The `[commitHash - 5 commits]` part is trivial, it would be `<commitHash>~5`, but since commit histories in git follow the principles of DAG (directed acyclic graphs), nothing in a commit is stored about its children, only its direct parent(s). By following parent(s)'s own ancestry you can go back until root commit(s), but not in the other direction.

Comment: @c0mr4t Of course, if you drop the "easy composed" part of your request... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2264471/1057485) could be interesting.