# How do I move forward and backward between commits in git?

Tags: git

I am doing a `git bisect` and after arriving to the problematic commit, I am now trying to get a step forward/backward to make sure I am in the right one.

I know of `HEAD^` to go backwards in history but is there another shortcut to get me forward (towards a specific commit in the future) like so:

```
A - B - C(HEAD) - D - E - F
```

I know that my target is **F** and I want to move from **C** to **D**.

---

NOTE: this is not a duplicate of [Git: How to move back and forth between commits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2121230/146272), my question is slightly different and is not answered there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git can help too.

Comment: `git checkout -b new_branch HEAD~4` to go back 4 commits from HEAD as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4940090/911945

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I've experimented a bit and this seems to do the trick to navigate forwards (**edit**: it works well only when you have a linear history without merge commits):

```
git checkout $(git rev-list --topo-order HEAD..towards | tail -1)
```

where `towards` is a SHA1 of the commit or a tag.

Explanation:

- the command inside `$()` means: get all the commits between current `HEAD` and `towards` commit (excluding `HEAD`), and sort them in the precedence order (like in `git log` by default -- instead of the chronological order which is weirdly the default for `rev-list`), and then take the last one (`tail`), i.e. the one we want to go to.
- this is evaluated in the subshell, and passed to `git checkout` to perform a checkout.

You can define a function accessible as a parameter-expecting alias in your `.profile` file to navigate forward towards the particular commit:

```
# Go forward in Git commit hierarchy, towards particular commit 
# Usage:
#  gofwd v1.2.7
# Does nothing when the parameter is not specified.
gofwd() {
  git checkout $(git rev-list --topo-order HEAD.."$*" | tail -1)
}

# Go back in Git commit hierarchy
# Usage: 
#  goback
alias goback='git checkout HEAD~'
```

Comment: Going forward works fine on straight parts of history but goes into loops when encountering a merge.

Comment: Yeah, I actually haven't tested it on merges. I'll try to to have a look in spare time, but I have little incentive temporarily, since we've agreed to have a strictly linear history in our project ;)

Comment: Great answer! Modified to automatically specify current branch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23172256/480608

Comment: This is incorrect. `git log` shows commits in chronological order, by default, the same as `rev-list`, except when using the `--graph` flag.

Comment: Pretty convincing evidence that git is too complex. For something that's usually as simple as Undo or Redo, here we have a crazy list of conflicting answers. And I haven't even gone into any of the linked answers. FWIW, I tried a version of this with a simple linear set of commits and finally just gave up.

Comment: By adding `forward = !sh -c \"git switch --detach $(git rev-list --topo-order HEAD.."$1" | tail -1)\"` to the `[alias]` section of your `.gitconfig`, you can enhance git with the `forward` sub command. For example, in order to move to master you'd enter `git forward master`.

Comment: For people working with merges, eg walking forwards on master taking only merge commits you can add `--first-parent` to `git rev-list`.

Answer (score 99):

I believe you can do:

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

To go one commit forward in time. To go forward multiple commits, use HEAD@{2}, HEAD@{3}, etc.

Comment: It doesn't seem to go anywhere

Comment: This works for when you use one too many `git reset --soft HEAD~1`

Comment: The temporary version: `git checkout HEAD@{1}`

Comment: Some terminals will require `HEAD@{1}` to be between quotes: 
`git checkout "HEAD@{1}"`

Comment: @Mehdi and others with this issue, see jakub.g 's comment about merges making it harder for git to know what you're telling it to do.  Common sense explanation: you only have one parent, but your parent may have many kids.  If you tell git to `git checkout mother`, there's an unambiguous parent to checkout, but `git checkout daughter` could give you multiple options if the mother has multiple daughters.  And you may also be facing where you're trying to checkout 3 commits forwards or backwards, meaning there's even more potential greatgranddaughters or greatgrandmothers to pick from :)

Answer (score 55):

All you need to get clear, not detached head state is to reset, not checkout.

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: or `git reset "HEAD@{1}"` in certain shells like fish and powershell.. `git reflog` can also be useful to find the correct commit.

Comment: Always use single quotes in shell commands unless you explicitly want the shell to attempt to interpret/expand the contents. This is especially important in cases like this, where the goal is to prevent the shell from interpreting special characters. That way, you don’t need to know whether the string contains anything that’s problematic.

Comment: I did that to have a look back in time, then I did `git reset HEAD` to go back to where I was... now I have no idea what state my repository is in and everything is scary. What should I do now?

Comment: That shouldn't have affected much, to make sure though you can just use `git checkout master` or any branch you want to go to.

Answer (score 32):

This is what I'm using to navigate back and forth.

**moving to next commit**

```
function n() {
    git log --reverse --pretty=%H master | grep -A 1 $(git rev-parse HEAD) | tail -n1 | xargs git checkout
}
```

**moving to previous commit**

```
function p() {
    git checkout HEAD^1
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using this now! **Notes for other beginners like me**: to reattach HEAD, `git checkout <current branch>` attaches to latest commit. `git checkout -b <new-branch-name>` from current commit allows changes in new branch. `git rebase -i` also works. **Also**, I named my `n()` function as `nx()` to avoid conflicting with node version manager "n". Make sure to check aliases!

Comment: function(){...} is for authoring a Unix/Linux bash scripting file, I come from Windows, a little hard for me to understand firstly

Answer (score 9):

Say F is the latest commit on `trunk` (insert your own branch name here) ... you can refer to it as `trunk~0` (or just `trunk`), E as `trunk~1`, D as `trunk~2` etc.

Take a look in your [reflog](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) for yet more ways to name commits.

Comment: ~ goes back, not foward, trunk~2 is A

Comment: Yes. This answer assumes you have a branch called trunk pointing to `F`, and that you know where in the history of that branch you want to move to. It's not trying to move forward relative to HEAD, but less-far-back relative to trunk.

Comment: @theonlygusti You move back from HEAD twice.

Comment: You're still assuming that the branch `trunk` and your current `HEAD` are identical which is _not_ shown in the question, which I've stated is _not_ what I'm assuming, and which is very unlikely half-way through a `bisect`

Answer (score 8):

Traversing backward is trivial since you are moving down the tree, and there's always one way to go

```
  function git_down
        git checkout HEAD^
  end
```

When traversing forward you are moving up the tree, so you need to be explicit which branch you are targeting:

```
  function git_up 
        git log --reverse --pretty=%H $argv | grep -A 1 (git rev-parse HEAD) | tail -n1 | xargs git checkout
  end
```

Usage: `git_down`, `git_up <branch-name>`

Comment: Going backward isn't entirely unique either, when merges are involved. Though `HEAD^` is usually a reasonable default.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see ahead, you can do this trick, as Git doesn't have strict command for it.

```
git log --reverse COMMIT_HASH..
```

#### Example

List of log history hashes:

```
A
B
C -> put this
D
```

using command `git log --reverse C..`, in output you will see **B** and **A**.

Comment: this is only going to work if you are not in commit `C`. Otherwise, you'll have to specify an ending commit or branch.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a test on this.
say for example you are in master branch
Then do:

```
git checkout HEAD@{3}
```

So head gets detached, and you can then try it again to go to any other commit:

```
git checkout HEAD@{4}
```

Once you are done looking around, you can go back to your original state just by checking out to that branch.  In my example: master branch

```
git checkout master
```

If you don't want to go to original state, and want so keep one of the commits as your head and continue from there, then you need to branch out from there.
for example after "git checkout HEAD@{4}" , you can issue

```
git checkout -b MyNewBranch
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm joining this comments a little bit later but I built this line of code that helped me go "forward" on any `git tree` and I hope you can find it useful as well.

Note that I am not a bash magician so if you find something that could be changed, comment and we can make this line of code a better one!

To go backward:

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline | grep -A 1 $(git rev-parse --short HEAD) | awk '{print $1}' | tail -1 | xargs -I {} git checkout {}
```

To go forward:

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline | grep -B 1 $(git rev-parse --short HEAD) | awk '{print $1}' | head -1 | xargs -I {} git checkout {}
```

Here is some explanation:

```
git reflog # Here we get all the commits we need

grep -A 1 $(git rev-parse --short HEAD) # Here we grep for the short commit hash

awk '{print $1}' # Here we get just the hash

tail -1 # We will get at least 2 results, pick the last line, the first would be 0

xargs -I {} git checkout {} # Here we go "forward by 1"
```

Hope this can be helpful to anyone that would like to get this same behaviour. I'm building a CLI which has a command that moves you "back and forth" in the commits tree without prior knowledge of hashes or logs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the nicest way but you can use `git log` to view the list of commits and then use `git checkout [sha1 of D]` to move to D.

Comment: I don't get it, if he's in C, then git log will only show him C,B and A.

Comment: Ok, got it, but you'll have to do a tricky git-log like indicated in the link given by VonC

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can just return to HEAD with

```
git checkout <branch>
```

And then move to the commit you'd like to, with

```
git checkout HEAD~<offset>
```

Comment: So there's no opposite `git checkout HEAD~<offset>` where it moves forward instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vs code then Git history is an awesome plugin where you can efficiently see commits and check their contents in the editor itself.
check out the [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory)

Answer (score 0):

```
branchName=master; commitInOrder=1; git checkout $(git log --pretty=%H "${branchName}" | tac | head -n "${commitInOrder}" | tail -n 1)
```

where:

`branchName` equals branch name

`commitInOrder` equals a commit in order from very first commit in the selected branch (so 1 is the very first commit, 2 is second commit in branch, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To GUI and vscode users I would recommend using the extension git graph

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use `git-reflog` and `git-reset`.

It is not the same case as you run `git-bisect`, but suppose you `git-reset` to commit C and want to move it back to commit F.

At the point, `git-reflog` looks like this:

```
$ git reflog show
4444444 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to 4444444
1111111 HEAD@{1}: commit: F
2222222 HEAD@{2}: commit: E
3333333 HEAD@{3}: commit: D
4444444 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{4}: commit: C
5555555 HEAD@{5}: commit: B
6666666 HEAD@{6}: commit: A
```

Then, you can run `git-reset` to go back to any commit by specifying SHA1 hash or offset number from HEAD.

In your case, run `git-reset` as follows:

```
$ git reset 1111111
```

or

```
$ git reset HEAD@{1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when I had to move to F I did `git checkout branch_name` which will move the HEAD to the latest commit in that particular branch

When I used `git reset HEAD{0}` all the changes I have made after the current commit (here it would be C) were changed to modified, which was not what I wanted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34712279)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, and it works fine most of the time. But if it cannot find the branch name, it will try to use the branch name from remote origin, which is a little slower and needs internet connection.

> **NOTE**: I haven't tried to handle all errors.

```bash
gn() {
    # Check if we're in a git repository
    if ! git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "Not in a git repository"
        return 1
    fi

    # Check if there are any commits in the current branch
    if ! git rev-parse HEAD > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "No commits in the current branch"
        return 1
    fi

    # Try to get the name of the remote branch that the HEAD points to
    local branch=""
    if git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/HEAD > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        branch=$(git branch -r --points-at refs/remotes/origin/HEAD | grep '\->' | cut -d' ' -f5 | cut -d/ -f2)
    fi

    if [ -z "$branch" ]; then
        # Fallback: Extract branch name another method
        branch=$(basename $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git/refs/heads/*)
    fi

    # If there's still no branch or an error, perform another fallback action
    if [ -z "$branch" ]; then
        local fallback_branch=$(git remote show origin | sed -n '/HEAD branch/s/.*: //p')
        local next_commit=$(git rev-list --topo-order HEAD..$fallback_branch | tail -1)
        git checkout $next_commit
        return
    fi

    # Get the hash of the next commit
    local next_commit=$(git log --reverse --pretty=%H $branch | grep -A 1 $(git rev-parse HEAD) | tail -n1)

    # If there's no next commit, we're already at the last commit
    if [ -z "$next_commit" ]; then
        echo "Already at the last commit"
        return 1
    fi

    # Try to checkout the next commit, and use the fallback command in case of an error
    git checkout $next_commit
}

gp() {
    if ! git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "Not in a git repository"
        return 1
    fi

    # Check if there are any commits in the current branch
    if ! git rev-parse HEAD > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "No commits in the current branch"
        return 1
    fi
  git checkout HEAD^1
}
```