# Git: how do I go back to a previous commit (just for testing)

Tags: git

I am facing an issue (compiling for Windows). I'm not sure if it an issue with the environment.

I know that a previous commit worked.

How do I:

1> Get that old commit, and after testing
2> Get back to the latest commit

I do not want to create branches, fork the code, or anything fancy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+temporarily+switch+previous+commit

Comment: `git checkout commit`, `git checkout branch`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759791/how-do-i-move-forward-and-backward-between-commits-in-git this may be helpful